# No identifier/primary key specified for Abstract Class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, abstract-class

I am trying implement [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) mapping strategy. I defined abstract class with id and other fields. but I keep getting following error:

> No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "AppBundle\Entity\AbstractItem". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key. (500 Internal Server Error)

This is my class. As you can see, unique identifier `$id` was specified

```
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
  * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
  * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"post" = "Post", "group" = "Group"})
  */
 class AbstractItem
 {
     /**
      * @var int
      *
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
      */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @var \DateTime
     */
     protected $published;
     protected $object;
     protected $target;

     /**
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function getId()
     {
         return $this->id;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try to set `$id`'s visibility to `protected`?

Comment: Doctrine uses the notion of Mapped Super Classes to deal with abstract entity classes: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping

Comment: @JakubMatczak it didn't help. I still have same error

Answer (score 0):

This abstract class shouldn't be an actual entity in the database.

Try to put @ORM\MappedSuperClass instead of @ORM\Entity

Comment: now I get ` [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                    
  It is not supported to define inheritance information on a mapped superclass` error

Comment: You really need InheritanceType and the stuff under it? I don't understand what was the purpose of it

Comment: I tried to implement this mapping strategy: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

try this please:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Instead of this:

```
  /**
  * @var int
  *
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
  */
 private $id;
```

You need to specify the column id inside comment